# Making certain GameObjects visible for a camera

Tags: unity, camera, culling

I have 2 cameras in my 2D game.

One displays gameobjects normally, and the other camera draws some of these gameobjects reflected (scale.y *= -1). The reflected camera would draw only objects in the "Water" layer, and I would change the layer of the GameObjects I want to reflect on the precull and postrender functions. This way I can decide which GameObjects would be reflected, changing the layer on the fly at runtime, which is a requirement.

```
-Precull: Change the desired GameObjects layer to "water", and apply scale.y*= -1

-OnPostRender:  Change the Gameobjects layer to their original value, and apply scale*= -1
```

This was working correctly when my objects were simple, but now my objects are more complex, and I can't rely on changing the layer of the gameobjectson the fly, as I can't tell what their original layer was for each part of the object, in order to revert the changes applied during the precull.

Is there anyway to tell a camera which objects should it render besides using the culling mask?

Answer (score 1):

You could use shaders instead.

Here is a link of one that may help
http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SurfaceReflection.